# R: Forecast the percentage growth

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have a data set of the percentage of the population covered by 4G mobile network, for a number of years, the data looks like this:

```
## # A tibble: 196 × 10
## # Groups:   Country [196]
##    Country        `2012` `2013` `2014` `2015` `2016` `2017` `2018` `2019` `2020`
##    <chr>           <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
##  1 Afghanistan       0      0        0    0     0       4      7     22     26  
##  2 Albania           0      0        0   35    80.2    85.3   85.5   95     98.4
##  3 Algeria           0      0        0    0     3.62   30.5   52.8   53.6   76.2
##  4 Andorra          50     50       50   50    50      85     85     85     85  
##  5 Angola            7      7        7    7     8       8      8     18     30  
##  6 Antigua and B…   65     78.6     80   98    99      99     99     99     99  
##  7 Argentina         0      0        0   65    85      85     90.8   91.2   97.7
##  8 Armenia          17.5   44       46   46.5  52.5    90.0   99.1   99.3  100  
##  9 Australia        52.2   85       95   94    98      99     99.2   99.4   99.5
## 10 Austria          31.6   58.4     85   98    98      98     98     98     98  
## # … with 186 more rows
```

I need to make forecasts for up until 2030 for each country, how can I do that while restraining the results to be between 0 and 100?

Comment: have you plotted some of these curves?

Comment: The Tobit model may be helpful in this case.